# Deixar panel invisível ao abrir Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Meu programa está abrindo um form2 dentro de um panel no form1, quero que quando eu feche este form2 o meu panel fique invisível

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panelPrinc.Visible = true;

            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            
            frm2.TopLevel = false;
            frm2.AutoScroll = true;

            panelPrinc.Controls.Add(frm2);

            frm2.Show();

            if ()
            {
                panelPrinc.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa criar um evento `FormClosed` para o Form2.

Seguindo a mesma ideia de código que você fez, eu adicionei a chamada ao evento.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelPrinc.Visible = true;
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.TopLevel = false;
    frm2.AutoScroll = true;
    panelPrinc.Controls.Add(frm2);
    
    //Esse evento será disparado no momento que o form2 for fechado
    frm2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form2Fechado);
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Ai você só precisa criar o metodo que recebe o evento dentro do seu Form principal

```
private void Form2Fechado(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   panelPrinc.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!